# With WXPython when is it necessary to use classes?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, wxpython

I'm very new to python and i have some stupid question, thank you for helping!

when I search online about wxpython questions, I see almost 100% of the people use class for wxpython. From the book i learnt, the author didn't mention using class for wxpython, instead he gave us a few examples that didn't use class.

I just want to know, when is it good to use class and when is it really not so necessary.

Comment: Perhaps it would be wise to refer to the book and some chosen example, so that we can actually compare the two code samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wxPython, you should use classes whenever you want to extend the functionality of something wxPython provides to you.

A lot of wxPython apps at the very least define a class inheriting from `wx.Frame` to serve as the main GUI. If you need to add special behavior to certain widgets (e.g. add a method to `wx.Button`), you might also want to write a class for that. Lastly, some special features in wxPython (like tabbed GUIs or wizards) require you to write a class for each page.

There's a lot of cases where you need to write a class. You almost always need to at least write one class for your main frame. Other than that, it depends on what kind of problems you're trying to solve.

I'm not sure what book you read, but if you haven't already I'd recommend [wxPython in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394621), which is really the definitive guide to wxPython.

Comment: This information is extremely helpful, but i have another question though, what are the consequences of not using a class.

Comment: @loolo78 you'll have a pretty tough time writing your app, I guess :)

Comment: I have a another question, thanks A LOT! This is the most helpful answer I ever got from the internet. OK, so my app needs a open and a save dialog, and I've got lucky enough to make the dialog work, but the thing is at the end where i think I'm suppose to write: `code`
`if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            paths = dlg.GetPaths()``\code`                        is not working right. How do i make it work?

Comment: @loolo78, you should open a new question for your question in your last comment, please include a relevant code sample and how it is not working right ("is not working right.  How do i make it work?" does not tell us anything).

Comment: @Mark Thank, i will next time, i just thought asking so many small questions wasn't good.

Answer (score 1):

You will **need** to use a class to overwrite the behavior of an existing Widget.

Many tutorials online start by using a custom extension of `wx.Frame` as the base window for the application, but in fact there is no real reason to do that.

If you are satisfied with everything that widgets normally provide out of the box there is no reason to use classes - in fact you should avoid Object Oriented Programming as much as possible. Using a more functional approach will result in cleaner code and less troubles.